# Are there any elementary category theory books for non-mathematicians?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, soft-question, book-recommendation

Mathematics, for me at least, is a symbolic language such that its words are abstract objects and its sentences are abstract concepts and relationships. Things like arithmetic, geometry, calculus and algebra are topics we discus in this language because its abstractness allows as to get more far and deep in these topics through generalization or abstraction as a main tool, and after this abstraction one sees that a lot of things are more connected in a deeper level.

Informally, I think the language of mathematics is the language of (structured-)sets and maps between them, and a lot of the fundamental ideas of math is about what maps tell us about these structures, like if two structures have an isomorphism between them then they are similar in a way, the easiest example is that two sets have the same number of elements if there is a bijective map between them, and this was probably discovered more than one time in history by those who discovered numbers, and humans subconsciously mostly compare quantities of things in this way by seeing if there is a 1-to-1 correspondence, then a number came as an equivalence class of things with the same quantity, this is an example of a kind of abstraction that all humans can think of, *without the mathematical terminology of course*.

Another easy generalization is the generalization of integers with addition, automorphisms of a set with composition to the more abstract *group*, one basically notes that both integers and automorphisms are sets with an operation defined for it's elements that satisfies some properties, so we make this more general structure a thing and call it a group.

So sets and maps or more generally these objects and arrows categorical way of thinking is a natural thing in humans and mathematics just formalizes it along with the method of abstraction or generalization in a symbolic language.

Based on this I think there can be books that introduce this view of math for common people or anybody through some elementary category theory, a lot of people think that mathematics is about computations and such a book if existed will show that math is a language that formalizes and emphasizes the categorical way of thinking that probably all humans use in some things like understanding numbers.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Category-Theory-Sciences-MIT-Press/dp/0262028131/

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Bake-Pi-recipes-understanding/dp/1781252882/

Comment: Not clear. Are you asking for a book which you can use to teach yourself or recommend to others? Or is your question intended to promote your ideas about the usefulness of such books?

Comment: @sammygerbil both, I'm giving my opinion on why such a books are useful, and I want a book like this for a friend of mine who started self-studying mathematics to just give him sort of a mathematical mindset.

Comment: thanks for the recommendations @AnginaSeng , going to take a look

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book that comes nearest to what you seem to have in mind is probably

> [Conceptual Mathematics: A First Introduction to Categories](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/logic-categories-and-sets/conceptual-mathematics-first-introduction-categories-2nd-edition?format=PB)

From the blurb: “Conceptual Mathematics is the first book to serve both as a skeleton key to mathematics for the general reader or beginning student and as an introduction to categories for computer scientists, logicians, physicists, linguists, etc ... The fundamental ideas are illuminated in an engaging way.” And that's a reasonably fair description.

Comment: this book is awesome, I think the first two parts of the book "the category of sets, the algebra of composition" is really near what I had in mind of introducing categorical thinking for a beginner in math, beautiful recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are! *How to Bake Pi* and *The Joy of Abstraction*, both by Eugenia Cheng. The first book is more of a popular math category theory book while the second one bridges the gap between everything covered in the first book and formal category theory textbooks. The second book starts without formalism in the first few chapters and later goes on to introduce some of the more serious category theory concepts.